# How to add a menu item into a File Type in Outlook

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, contextmenu, outlook-addin

I'm trying to **create a Export method** of a **VCF file** to our CRM application.

I'm running the new VS 2010 but target the project as .NET 3.5

what is the technique to **hook up into this context menu**?

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-14_1523.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-14_1523.png)

I'm very new to AddIns but as a logical line of thought is to create an Outlook AddIn, but **I'm failing miserably** to add a menu item to this context menu :(

Thank you for any help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-14_1604.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-14_1604.png)

```
this.Application.AttachmentContextMenuDisplay += 
    new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_AttachmentContextMenuDisplayEventHandler(ThisAddIn_AttachmentContextMenuDisplay);
```

and then in the eventHandler

```
private void ThisAddIn_AttachmentContextMenuDisplay(Office.CommandBar commandBar, Outlook.AttachmentSelection attachments)
{
    if (attachments.Count > 0)
    {
        Office.CommandBarControl cbc = commandBar.Controls.Add(
                  Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 
                  missing, missing, missing, true);

        cbc.Caption = "Export into SuperOffice";
        cbc.OnAction = "Action";
    }
}
```